# Magento 2 with sample data not showing stock quantity on the frontend

Tags: frontend, stock-status, magento-2.1.2

I've installed an fresh installation of `Magento 2` with the sample data. I configured the products to show the stock quantity on the frontend. Followed [this](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-stock-in-magento-2.html) instructions to be sure.

After that flushed and cleared the cache and reindex. The stock quantity does not show on the frontend. Another installation has the same issue. Both using 2.1.2

Comment: what do you mean by stick quantity ?

Answer (score 0):

What did you insert into '`Notify for quantity below`'? It should show stock quantity on frontend only when stock quantity for this product is less or equal than this number. So, if you have only 1 item in stock, it will show, otherwise not.